# Use `removeshard` to remove a shard, but it's not work well

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In my MongoDB sharding cluster, i used `db.runCommand( { removeshard: "shard3" } )` command to remove a shard "shard3", but it just puts the shard in draining mode, which will never end and three days past. All chunks of the shard "shard3" are moved into "shard1" or "shard2", but the APP read request can use it to query data. So i want to know which process of the sharding now or how to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a database using `shard3` as its primary shard, check the output of `db.printShardingStatus()` to see where each database resides.

Once you figure out which database it is, [move it to a different shard](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/#move-unsharded-databases) with the `movePrimary` command. Then run `removeShard` again and you should be good to go.

Comment: It is confirmed that there is a unsharded database test on the shard "shard3" and "shard3" is not the primary shard, then i drop "test" database and re-run `removeshard` command. It is success to remove the "shard3". From document, "Do not run the movePrimary until you have finished draining the shard". But our program also use the "shard3" with 3 nodes replicaset to query data. Why not to router APP requests to other available shards by mongos server?

Comment: You do need to run movePrimary to complete draining in the case of a db being on the primary.  If you look at the results of the `removeshard` and see `"chunks" : NumberLong(0)` but `"dbs": NumberLong(` some number other than 0 `)` you probably have a DB whose primary is the shard you are removing and will probably have to run movePrimary even though `removeshard` hasn't said "draining is complete".  Check out this discussion on [mongodb-user](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/CiOAjdlMOT8/discussion) for more information: